# Generate jQuery functions dynamically mvc 4 razor

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

Currently, I am passing a list of object from controller to a view, and generate labels by the object's name.

What I am trying to do is to generate a jQuery function that will Dynamically create functions (toggle a form with relative lable id) for each label after being clicked.

The jQuery function is not working, I could not output the corrent jQuery function in the webpage......  Could you give me soem hints?

```
<table>
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.Label(item.productName, new { @id = item.productId})
            </td>
        </tr>    
    }
</table>


<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        $(@item.productId).click)(function({
            //do something
       }));
    }

    });
</script>
```

Thanks very much!

Comment: your JS syntax is wrong, for starters. `$('@item.productId').on('click', function() {});` is more what you want, however a cheaper and faster way is to give all those labels a class name, and only have one click handler; ie `$('.product_lbl').on('click', function() { /* Do something for whichever label was clicked */ });`

Comment: Also, `$('#idGoesHere')` would help.

Answer (score 2):

your JS syntax is wrong, for starters. What you want to do is to give all those labels a class name (such as `product_lbl`) or a data attribute (if you don't like semantic class names) such as `product-lbl`. This way you don't have to do a second loop to add click event handlers. You'll only need one, like so:

```
$('.product_lbl').on(
    'click', 
    function() { /* Do something for whichever label was clicked */ }
);
```

OR

```
$('[product-lbl]').on(
    'click', 
    function() { /* Do something for whichever label was clicked */ }
);
```